# Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection - loading file MAC

Tags: r, input, osx-yosemite

I read all other questions related to this error, however they do not seem to solve my problem. I am trying to load a SAS file in R (and tried RStudio as well) using a MAC. Hence, with windows I do not have any problems. I tried the following code and even re-installed R and RStudio. Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
install.packages("sas7bdat")      
library(sas7bdat)
kollektiv <- read.sas7bdat("/Volumes/JOJO/Bonn/2. Food composition data-DONALD/complete.sas7bdat")

Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'Volumes/JOJO/Bonn/2. Food composition data-DONALD/Intake across and within DONALD/complet.xpt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome. Just a few notes - i know nothing about this file format. 1) there are two different file path names. The one you provide and the one reported in the error 2) the one you provide is absolute (begins with /) the other, in the error message is not  3) Try setting your working directory to the *parent* directory of Volumes and change to providing a relative path (no starting /). 4) my guess is that this file format may reference other files from within it. 5) try add debug=TRUE